# Does Spring MVC 3 have view components?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, components

I'm learning Spring 3 MVC for a project I'll start soon for a client and I can't find if it supports view components (similar in a way to portlets).

Ideally the solution would be similar to Rails, in which invoking "render" with a parameter (object or view name) renders the component.

OR to have something like the following in the view template

```
<component name="search" paramA="1" paramB="2"/>
```

and in this case, there's something that searches for the component "Search" in the classpath and initializes it with the parameters.

The ideal solution should have 0 configuration. Maybe the solution would be to write a custom taglib that does this for me, but I'm wondering if there's something already done out there.

I would be really thankful If anyone knows about a book / tutorial that explains spring mvc 3 from a Rails developer point of view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring MVC isn't a component framework - it's too low level for that.

The Java world is awash with more web-based component frameworks than you can shake a widget at.  Try (in no particular order) JSF, Spring WebFlow, PlayFramework, Vaadin, etc.

If you're already familiar with Rails, then the obvious choice is Grails - it's inspired by the Rails approach, uses Groovy rather than Java, but runs on the Java VM, and integrates with other Java stuff well.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion about Spring Web Flow, I haven't checked it because I thought it was more a tool to build "wizards" than components. Unfortunately, this customer invested heavily on spring technology and they prefer the app to be build with Spring Something. Play would be amazing for this project as the app must be restful too :(

Comment: @Augusto: Grails is owned and maintained by SpringSource (http://www.grails.org/). Doesn't get much more officially-Spring than that :)  If you want REST, then Spring MVC is your best bet. That will sit alongside Grails or WebFlow just fine.